# Simple, passing attributes Spring MVC misconception

Tags: spring, jsp, model-view-controller, spring-mvc

Hello everyone thanks for helping alot people all over the world.

Guys I try for two past days just simply pass attributes between request methods in my cntroller, tried alot's of different ways, but nothing happend. I have bean CreationDate and I need fill up by form properties in that bean and simply render them on my second page. I see in my url bar in browser that it's passing(cuz I do GET method for passing) but it's nothing appears on second page just blank list.

My controller class:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4825408935018763217L;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);  

    @Autowired
    private ControllerSupportClass controllerSupportClass; 


        public void setControllerSupportClass(
                ControllerSupportClass controllerSupportClass) {
            this.controllerSupportClass = controllerSupportClass;
        }




        @RequestMapping(value ="/index", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String index(Model model) {
            CreationDate creationDate = new CreationDate();
            model.addAttribute("creationD", creationDate);
            return "index";
        }



        @RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String addingData(@ModelAttribute("creationD") CreationDate creationDate, BindingResult result, Model model) {

            model.addAttribute("creationD", creationDate);

            return "add";

        }

}
```

My bean:

```
public class CreationDate implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1648102358397071136L;


    private int dateId;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)
        @Column(name="DATE_ID")
        public int getDateId() {
            return dateId;
        }

        public void setDateId(int dateId) {
            this.dateId = dateId;
        }


    private Date particularDate;

        @Column(name="PARTICULAR_DATE")
        public Date getParticularDate() {
            return particularDate;
        }

        public void setParticularDate(Date particularDate) {
            this.particularDate = particularDate;
        }


    private int version;

        @Version
        @Column(name="VERSION")
        public int getVersion() {
            return version;
        }

        public void setVersion(int version) {
            this.version = version;
        }


    private Date childGoSchoolDate;

        @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
        @Column(name="CHILD_GO_SCHOOL_DATE")
        public Date getChildGoSchoolDate() {
            return childGoSchoolDate;
        }

        public void setChildGoSchoolDate(Date childGoSchoolDate) {
            this.childGoSchoolDate = childGoSchoolDate;
        }


    private Date childAdmissionDate;

        @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
        @Column(name="CHILD_ADMISSION_DATE")
        public Date getChildAdmissionDate() {
            return childAdmissionDate;
        }

        public void setChildAdmissionDate(Date childAdmissionDate) {
            this.childAdmissionDate = childAdmissionDate;
        }   

}
```

My form page:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>      
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Страница выборки</title>
</head>

<body>

<h3>Вставка данных:</h3>

<form:form modelAttribute="creationD" method="GET" action="add">


<form:label path="particularDate">Particular Date</form:label>
<form:input path="particularDate" /> <br>

<form:label path="childGoSchoolDate">Child go to School</form:label>
<form:input path="childGoSchoolDate"/> <br>


<form:label path="childAdmissionDate">Child admission Date</form:label>
<form:input path="childAdmissionDate"/> <br>


<input type="submit" value="Save"/>

</form:form>

</body>

</html>
```

My second page where I need to rented data from my form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>    
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Result:</h1>

Attribute 1:<c:out value="${creationD.particularDate}"/>
Attribute 2:<c:out value="${creationD.childGoSchoolDate}"/>
Attribute 3:<c:out value="${creationD.childAdmissionDate}"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check following to isolate the problem:

- Have you got a date resolver? You have a property of type Date on your form bean, Spring wouldn't automatically know the date format unless you tell it. On Spring 3.2.3 you can simply [use `@DateTimeFormat` annotation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#format-CustomFormatAnnotations)
- Have you setup view resolver properly? I'm assuming "index" and "add" resolves to index.jsp and add.jsp, make sure you're not editing the wrong file
- Have you got any [Spring MVC handler interceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor) / servlet filters that mess around with stuff in your model?

Comment: Yeah Thank you gerrytan. All mentioned by you are realy important to know. I may get better understanding for all of this to solve the problem. And it's all true that I do not know good enough this topics, but I should. Thank you.

Comment: You know the problem was in @DateTimeFormat. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

v.a,

Try this:

Note: I commented out the logging in your controller to save time. You can add that back in.
I also took the database annotations out of your controller, again to save time, and I also changed the way you were building your attributes in the /add routine to a style I was familiar with. 
Last but not least, I also changed the way you were displaying your output slightly..

web.xml:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" 
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"  
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee  
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"> 

  <display-name>Spring MVC Form Handling</display-name> 

  <servlet> 
      <servlet-name>Student</servlet-name> 
      <servlet-class> 
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet 
      </servlet-class> 
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
  </servlet> 

  <servlet-mapping> 
      <servlet-name>Student</servlet-name> 
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> 
  </servlet-mapping> 

</web-app>
```

Student-servlet.xml‏:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation=" 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans      
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd"> 

<context:component-scan base-package="com.hcsc" /> 

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"> 
   <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" /> 
   <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" /> 
</bean> 

</beans>
```

CreationDate.Java:

```
package com.hcsc; 

import java.util.Date; 

public class CreationDate { 

private int dateId; 

    public int getDateId() { 
        return dateId; 
    } 

    public void setDateId(int dateId) { 
        this.dateId = dateId; 
    } 


  private Date particularDate; 
    public Date getParticularDate() { 
        return particularDate; 
    } 

 public void setParticularDate(Date particularDate) { 
        this.particularDate = particularDate; 
    } 


 private int version; 
    public int getVersion() { 
        return version; 
    } 

 public void setVersion(int version) { 
        this.version = version; 
    } 


 private Date childGoSchoolDate; 
    public Date getChildGoSchoolDate() { 
        return childGoSchoolDate; 
    } 

 public void setChildGoSchoolDate(Date childGoSchoolDate) { 
        this.childGoSchoolDate = childGoSchoolDate; 
    } 


 private Date childAdmissionDate; 
    public Date getChildAdmissionDate() { 
        return childAdmissionDate; 
    } 

 public void setChildAdmissionDate(Date childAdmissionDate) { 
        this.childAdmissionDate = childAdmissionDate; 
    }    
}
```

HomeController.java:

```
package com.hcsc; 

  import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller; 
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute; 
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping; 
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod; 
  import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView; 
  import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap; 

@Controller 
public class HomeController{ 


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4825408935018763217L;
```

//     @SuppressWarnings("unused") 
 //     private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

```
      @RequestMapping(value ="/index", method=RequestMethod.GET) 
      public ModelAndView index() { 
        return new ModelAndView("index","command", new CreationDate()); 
    } 

    @RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.GET) 
    public String addingData(@ModelAttribute("creationD")CreationDate creationDate, ModelMap   model) { 

            model.addAttribute("particularDate", creationDate.getParticularDate()); 
            model.addAttribute("childGoSchoolDate", creationDate.getChildGoSchoolDate()); 
            model.addAttribute("childAdmissionDate", creationDate.getChildAdmissionDate()); 

        return "add"; 

    } 
}
```

index.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %> 
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="utf-8"%> 
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>       
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 

<html> 

<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
<title>Страница выборки</title> 
</head> 

<body> 

<h3>Вставка данных:</h3> 

<form:form method="GET" action="/Student/add"> 


<form:label path="particularDate">Particular Date</form:label> 
<form:input path="particularDate" /> <br> 

<form:label path="childGoSchoolDate">Child go to School</form:label> 
<form:input path="childGoSchoolDate"/> <br> 


<form:label path="childAdmissionDate">Child admission Date</form:label> 
<form:input path="childAdmissionDate"/> <br> 


<input type="submit" value="Save"/> 

</form:form> 

</body> 

</html>
```

add.jsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0   Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
<title>Student UI Output</title> 
</head> 
<body> 

<h1>Result:</h1> 

Attribute 1: <c:out value="${particularDate} "/><br /> 
Attribute 2: <c:out value="${childGoSchoolDate} "/><br /> 
Attribute 3: <c:out value="${childAdmissionDate} "/><br /> 

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Yeas Thank you very much wSchmidt, it's realy works. Could you please tell me what is my problem is, what I did wrong? And what is the mechanism to pass attributes between methods inside controller? Thank you for your help